# Properly handling errors

Tags: go, error-handling

Typically in Go you find the following convention:

```
res, err := thingThatCanError(arg)

if err != nil {
        // handle it
}
```

However, it's obvious this gets VERY unruly very quickly for a large number of these calls:

```
res, err := thingThatCanError(arg)

if err != nil {
        // handle it
}

res, err2 := thingThatCanError(arg)

if err2 != nil {
        // handle it
}

res, err3 := thingThatCanError(arg)

if err3 != nil {
        // handle it
}
```

There's more lines of boilerplate error handling than code! [This website](http://www.golangpatterns.info/error-handling) says to *avoid* this but does not give an example on how to clean up this smell. A useful example comes straight from the [Go blog](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) that shows us how to clean up a homogenous HTTP app with an error handler that makes sense.

But imagine each of these calls aren't homogenous, as in with the same "central idea", so a single "error handler struct" wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Is there a way to clean up this type of code smell with functions that don't "mesh together" nicely in terms of errors?

Comment: I think what that site is getting at is keeping the errors local to the call. Using `err1`, `err2`, `err3`, implies that you have a reason to initialize a new error value each time for comparison later, which leads to confusing error handling.

Comment: Yes, it looks painful when you write such code in GO. But, if you want to build a stable software instead of spending lot of time for debugging and finding errors after some programmers wrote tons of code ignoring any errors. It something may fail, it'll fail. My suggest is to check every error and log it. Later you will say thanks to yourself for doing this.

Comment: "However, it's obvious this gets VERY unruly very quickly for a large number of these calls" No it does not. You have 3 different "failure" path and need to handle them. Doing this is not "very unruly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's sometimes no way around these patterns. You *could* use panic/defer as a makeshift try/catch system but the community looks down upon it.

If statements in Go can be combined with assignments so

```
err := thing.Do()
if err != nil {
   return err
}
```

can become

```
if err := thing.Do(); err != nil {
   return err
}
```